# IIS 7.0 asp.net session timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ssl

I have the following request:
I have a website with 2 areas

> 1) public - session is set for 10 minutes dynamically in code (during
>   page request processing)
>  2) private - session is set for one hour
>   dynamically in code (during page request processing)

My problem is that I have 2 environments that act differently:

> 1. Development environment - reacts as expected (public and private areas have the definitions that were defined by code).
> 2. Production environment - all areas have 15 (or 20) minutes session timeout (the timing depends on which server I define the
>      environment).

Due to the description, I understand that the code itself is not necessary.

Now, the only difference between the 2 environments is that Production has SSL encryption.

What do I need to add in order to make both environments act the same?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the setting in IIS itself.  I believe the default is 20 minutes, which may explain why you are seeing what you are seeing.

> - Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For    information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7).
>     For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see
>     Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).
> - In Features View, double-click ASP.
> - On the ASP page, under Services, expand Session Properties.
> - In the Time-out field, enter a time-out value in the format hh:mm:ss.    For example, enter 00:15:00 for 15 minutes.
> - In the Actions pane, click Apply.

From:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've tried it... nevertheless - I need it to be modified at runtime (that's why I do it in code).

Comment: Yep - the issue was about SSL and ASP.NET, and yes - they do not share the same Session ID by default, I've added in the web.config the option (in system.webserver section) that they should share the same ASP Session, and viola - it works!

Probably there is another way - but I do not think there is a way to make this work via code... (since it will have security issues with SSL or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows Event Log to ensure that the Worker Process is not being forced to recycle.

There may be something in your code that causes the Worker Process to force itself to recycle in which case when the session is stored `inProc` it will loose all session values it's holding.

Comment: Can you explain what is "inProc Session"? Does it differ from SSL Session or an IIS Session? I know that defining Session Settings in IIS works only on classic ASP sites (and not necessarily on ASP.NET).

Comment: BTW, the worker process didn't recycle in both environments. Still, Session has ended (expectedly and unexpectedly on both environments).